# Popup image below button

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am experiencing problems on my attempt to popup an image in my view.
I have created a new subclass of UIView (UIViewImageOverlay.m) with the image.

UIViewImageOverlay.m

```
//  ImageOverlay.m
//  ButtonPopup
//
//

#import "UIViewImageOverlay.h"

@implementation UIViewImageOverlay

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpeg"];
    int w = myImage.size.width;
    int h = myImage.size.height;
    CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h), myImage.CGImage);
    CGContextRelease(contextRef);
}


@end
```

In my ViewController.m i have a button `pushPush` to load the view, but the attempt gives a warning

```
//  ViewController.m
//  ButtonPopup
//
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "UIViewImageOverlay.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize viewImageOverlay;



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; // static
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{

    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

- (IBAction)pushPush:(id)sender {
    [self.view addSubview:self.viewImageOverlay];
}
@end
```

ViewController.h

```
//  ViewController.h
//  ButtonPopup
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class UIViewImageOverlay;


@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    UIViewImageOverlay *viewImageOverlay;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) UIViewImageOverlay *viewImageOverlay; 
- (IBAction)pushPush:(id)sender;
@end
```

UIViewImageOverlay.h

```
//  ImageOverlay.h
//  ButtonPopup
//
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIViewImageOverlay : UIView

@end
```

`[self.view addSubview:self.viewImageOverlay];` reports `Incompatible pointer types sending 'UIViewImageOverlay *' to parameter of type 'UIView *'`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the header for UIViewImageOverlay
?

Comment: where is the definition of the property `viewImageOverlay` ?

Comment: From what I see here it should work.... @t_motooka question might reveal this mystery :)

Comment: Woops! My bad, the viewcontroller.h is included now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare instance variable viewImageOverlay and define it as a property

Comment: Please see my updated code with ViewController.h source. Thanks

Comment: is there a reason why you custom draw the UIView instead of using the UIImageView?

Comment: i did not consider that at all. Do i have the same abilities as a custom draw?

Comment: depends on what you want to do. see the documentation to see if the class fits your need.

Comment: UIImageViewer is indeed easier as i can see. But can i archieve the custom positioning which i need for this purpose?

Comment: Ill go with this solution, it seems to be more staight forward by position in a rectangle with the image as background.

Comment: positioning as you saw yourself is rather simple. Your custom draw method is most likely not called because you dont declare it in the respective header file.

Answer (score 1):

You have a forward class declaration in your controller's header file (`@class UIViewImageOverlay`). It shadows the correct implementation.

Include `UIViewImageOverlay.h` in the implementation file of your controller

Comment: I added `#import "UIViewImageOverlay.h"` on the top of `ViewController.m`. The warning is resolved now, but no image popping up. Most likely another problem now.